# theano - how to efficiently replicate and add tensors?

Tags: theano

I have one tensor in shape (2, G) and another in shape (N, 2).

I need to add them in such a way that the output is (N, 2, G), meaning that the first tensor is replicated to (N, 2, G) and then the second tensor is added to each matrix along the third dimension. (or vice versa: the second tensor is replicated to (N, 2, G) and the first one is added to every sub-tensor along the first dimension).

How can this done efficiently in Theano?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an attempt to understand the problem, the following example is assumed to be representative.

If

```
A = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6]]
```

and

```
B = [[1, 2],
     [3, 4],
     [5, 6],
     [7, 8]]
```

then the result should be

```
C = [[[  2.   3.   4.]
      [  6.   7.   8.]]
     [[  4.   5.   6.]
      [  8.   9.  10.]]
     [[  6.   7.   8.]
      [ 10.  11.  12.]]
     [[  8.   9.  10.]
      [ 12.  13.  14.]]]
```

Here `G=3` and `N=4`.

To achieve this in Theano, one need only add new broadcastable dimensions and rely on broadcasting to get the desired result.

```
import numpy
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt

x = tt.matrix()
y = tt.matrix()
z = x.dimshuffle('x', 0, 1) + y.dimshuffle(0, 1, 'x')
f = theano.function([x, y], outputs=z)
print f(numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]), numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]))
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! It looks like the dumshuffle just adds another dimension. Is it more efficient than using numpy.newaxis?

Comment: Adding a broadcastable dimension via Theano's `dimshuffle` is probably equivalent to adding a dimension via numpy's `newaxis`. Both are trivial operations so efficiency isn't really an issue.